# How to assign var variable to String in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have below two variables in JSP page. now I need to assign name to hello how can i do that ?

```
var name = 'Hello World'
<%
String hello ="";
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, there's many mistakes on your code. You're mixing java code with javascript code.

Java runs on the server, and javascript lives on your browser, once the page is loaded.

You can assign a value to some javascript variable using java, but not all the way around.

In short, you can do this:

```
<% 
String name = 'Hello world'; //this is the java variable
%>

var hello = "<%=name%>"; //this is the javascript variable being initialized with the value of the java variable.
```

When your JSP runs, you'll see this on your page's source code:

```
var hello = "Hello world";
```

Also, you need to add the  tags around your JS code